# Laravel - How to pass a single database instance at a time to the queue job for processing?

Tags: database, laravel, queue, instance, laravel-5.5

I have a list of websites in my MySQL Database. I need to crawl these websites using PHP `file_get_html` method (provided by [Simple HTML DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)). When I try to parse each website, it takes huge time and the execution time limit is exceeded. And I need to keep crawling these websites every 30 mins. So to manage this, I am trying implement queue, which I guess would be the right solution.

This is sample data table:

```
Id | Website Name |  Website Source
1  | Website 1    |  www.website1.com
2  | Website 2    |  www.website2.com
3  | Website 3    |  www.website3.com
4  | Website 4    |  www.website4.com
```

But, I am facing issues when I try to send a database instance to the queue. This is my controller function:

```
 public function queueAllLinks(){
        include('simplehtmldom_1_5/simple_html_dom.php');
        
            $sourceObj = SourceDetails::all();
        
            foreach($sourceObj as $sourceObj) {    
            
                CrawlLinks::dispatch($sourceObj);
        }
    }
```

I am dispatching to job CrawlLinks. This is my job class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;
use App\SourceDetails;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
class CrawlLinks implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct()
    {
        
    }

    public function handle(SourceDetails $sourceObj) {
        $source_url = $sourceObj->website_source;
        $source_name = $sourceObj->website_name;
        $source_id = $sourceObj->id;
        $html = file_get_html($source_url);

        //process and save data in code    
        
    }
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work. And I am getting the following error:

```
local.ERROR: Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Jobs\CrawlLinks::__construct() must be an instance of App\SourceDetails, instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection given, called in D:\Projects\marathinews\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable.php on line 14
```

I tried to find solutions but all the sources use 'email' example. None of the sources explains about database instance.

PS - I am new to Laravel Queues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to above problem was to dumpautoload using command `composer dumpautoload`. I have to run this command everytime I make any changes to my Queue Jobs and then only run queue worker. Otherwise, I guess, changes are not reflected in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$sourceObject` is being serialized when sent to the queue, and deserialized during the handle method. Why dont you try to change your parameter to be an `..Eloquent\Collection` object instead of `App\SourceDetails` and see if anything happen?